# What's the most acceptable name for the "put or call" attribute of an option contract?

Tags: options, database

Very mundane question.  My team is setting up a security master db that includes listed option contracts.  I'd like to store the "put or call" attribute in a well-named field, one that won't be confused with other concepts.

- OptionType seems too vague.  It could refer to the contract size or the type of underlying security (stock, bond, index).
- OptionSide seems ambiguous with the concept of a long or short position.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have seen Right used often.  As in the Right that the owner of the option has.

Comment: Good idea, but it could be confusing because it sounds like "write", as in to write a covered call.

Comment: You could call it Option Directionality but is an ugly word.Option Type is probably best, and frequently used. PorC is the vairiable I use in my code.

Comment: `CallOrPut` or `IsPut` as a bit.

Comment: If i'm in `.Net` then i'll have a `CallPut` enum, and then the property is just `CallPut`.

Comment: Maybe "_style_", although might be confused with European style, American style, etc.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw style would almost certainly be confused with exercise style.

Comment: @will that is why I skipped the "_exercise_" part, to diminish confusion, but nevertheless I guess it is still ambiguous and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hull (Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives) calls that the "type" of the option (emphasis added):

> there are two **types** of options. A ***call*** option... A ***put*** option...

So does [NASDAQ](http://www.nasdaq.com/investing/options-guide/option-types-puts-calls.aspx):

> **Option Types: Calls & Puts**

I have seen `optionType` used in many places to identify if the option is a call or put.  I certainly wouldn't complain about `PutCall` or some other more specific name, but `Type` should not conflict with other attributes.

> OptionType seems too vague. It could refer to the contract size or the type of underlying security (stock, bond, index).

I can't see how the contract size could be considered a "type".  I would consider stock, bonds, index, etc. the type of the *underlying*, which *could* be an attribute on the option, but would be more appropriate in a separate entity that represents the underlying instrument.

*To be fair, there are also sites that call American and European the "type" of the option, but I have always seen that called the `exerciseType` to disambiguate that from put/call.

Comment: IMO in a programming context, `Type` is too vague. Exercise type, Instrument type, Underlying type, Settlement type, Strike type, Exotic type to name a few.

Comment: @msitt fair enough, but the context should disambiguate it. InstrumentType would be the Type on a more general Instrument table/class. UnderlyingType would the the Type on an underlying instrument.   (not sure what SettlementType, Strike Type, and ExoticType are to know how to classify those).  My point is OptionType is not a _completely ambiguous_ term.  PutCallType would be less ambiguous, but is not an industry standard term.

Comment: Yes, I'm being slightly pedantic. In the context of an option, I too would guess Type is Call or Put.

Answer (score 0):

**CallPutIndicator**

As others have mentioned "Type" and "Class" are too generic to be used here.